# DateTime Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am building a very basic database in SSMS, one table of which will hold "sleep instances" recording the time of falling asleep and waking up. I have created the table with three columns: ID (int), StartTime (DateTime), EndTime (DateTime). I am now trying to add the first row:

```
INSERT INTO SleepInstances
VALUES (1, 2022-07-05 22:20:00, 2022-07-06 06:40:00);
```

And I get a syntax error on the StartTime hour (22). As far as I can tell it is formatted correctly and identically to the EndTime value, which gives me no errors.

The only answers I can find about time issues seem to be related to time zones, which I can't imagine being the issue here as I get the error no matter what hour I try.
I am very new to SQL, so all of this is based off W3 Schools page on date functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify datetime literals as a string in SQL Server. I.e., enclose it in single-quotes. It should be something along the lines of below:

```
INSERT INTO SleepInstances
VALUES (1, '2022-07-05 22:20:00', '2022-07-06 06:40:00');
```

However, since the you say that the data type is datetime, you should use a language neutral datetime format, like for instance below:

```
INSERT INTO SleepInstances
VALUES (1, '2022-07-05T22:20:00', '2022-07-06T06:40:00');
```

If the data type would have been datetime2, then the first format would also have been language neutral. I have elaborated on this and  much more in [this](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) article.